# Slack icon not visible in top right corner in ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, slack

When I restart the Ubuntu system, slack application is not visible in the top right corner.

How to solve that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Restart GNOME shell. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, and then type `r` in the pop-up Run a Command window and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to restart GNOME Shell without interfering with any already opened windows.

---

Alternatively you can run the following to command restart GNOME Shell by replacing the running window manager:

Open the terminal and type:

```
setsid gnome-shell --replace
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again before you close the terminal.

`setsid gnome-shell --replace` restarts the GNOME shell without closing any open applications. For example, after restarting the GNOME shell an existing Firefox window and all of its existing tabs would remain open.

Comment: It would be nice of you to also add an explanation of what it exactly does.

Comment: @jave.web I added an explanation,

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 18.04, be cautious using:

```
setsid gnome-shell --replace
```

If you lock your computer, you will be unable to log back in. You will be stuck with an `Authentication Incorrect` error and will need to do a hard reset due to your keyboard not working for the login screen (no way to get to a shell either).

On Ubuntu 18.04, you can run:

```
killall -HUP gnome-shell
```

This will restart this as expected and has no negative affects